# Checking negative of a condition

Tags: coding-style, terminology

What is the (slightly pejorative) term for checking the negative of a condition (rather than the positive which is often more readable):

e.g.

```
if(!someVar) {
  return null;
} else {
  return doSomethingInteresting();
}
```

instead of doing this (which is arguably more readable)

```
if(someVar) {
  return doSomethingInteresting();
} else {
  return null;
}
```

I vaguely remember there being a term for this; something in the same spirit as the term [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: Sometimes this is done because people prefer to put the more-usual case up top and the less-usual case in the else.  There's not really a penalty for this; any compiler with a decent optimizer will sort it out.

Comment: I personally find an initial `if (!someArg) return;` -without explicitly coding the `else` much more readable, at least in C or C++ code. Coding a long `if (someArg) { /*a very long body*/ } else return;` is IMHO a mistake, or at least poor taste because it is much less readable!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch if I have an `if` block that long, I typically extract it to its own function. Then the original function is `if A then B else C` where `B` and `C` are functions (or simple `return`s). I find that helps make the code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The general term is "negative logic."

Circuit designers use it frequently as [negative logic](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1274544) can lead to simpler circuit design than the comparable positive logic design.

But be forewarned that trying to pin down the semantics of [negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) can be a slippery slope.

> No agreement exists as to the possibility of defining negation, as to its logical status, function, and meaning, as to its field of applicability..., and as to the interpretation of the negative judgment, (F.H. Heinemann 1944)

Comment: If I remember correctly, one can construct almost any other logic gate from [NAND gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) (Wikipedia says "yes").

Comment: @Snowman - That's correct.  [Because the NAND function has functional completeness all logic systems can be converted into NAND gates. This is also true of NOR gates. In principle, any combinatorial logic function can be realized with enough NAND gates.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic)